# Arbitrary Code Execution with Docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm thinking about building a web app that would involve users writing small segments of python and the server testing that code. However, this presents a ton of security concerns. Would docker be a good isolation tool for running this potentially malicious code? From what I've read, checking system calls with ptrace is a possibility, but I would prefer to use a preexisting tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker is indeed very suitable for this kind of usage. However, please note that docker is NOT yet ready for production usage.

I would recommend to create a new container and give non-root privileges to your users to this container. One container per user.

This way, you can prepare your docker image and prepare the environment and control precisely what your users are doing :)

Comment: If I construct a base ubuntu image dedicated to processing the arbitrary code, is there any easy way to start from the original image every few hours?

Comment: @MarkBerger: imo the basic idea is that you start every request (new container) from the same (clean) image. you do not need to commit file system changes so every new request will have the same clean environment.

Comment: Awesome, that would be even better. Thanks for all the info.